# Javascript Multiplying Within an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array with multiple arrays inside.  I would like to multiply the contents of each array.

Here is my code--currently not getting anything in console.
The desired output is 3 numbers-- the result of multiplication of the three arrays

```js
var arr = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [3, 4],
  [7, 8, 9]
]
var mult = 1
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
    mult *= arr[i][j]
  }
  console.log(mult)
}
```

Comment: It seems that the inner `j` loop should range from 0 to `arr[i].length`.

Answer (score 2):

You could map the result of the nested multiplying.

```js
const
    multiply = (a, b) => a * b,
    array = [[1, 2, 3], [3, 4], [7, 8, 9]],
    result = array.map(a => a.reduce(multiply, 1));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: The reduce method's 2nd parameter, here the initial value of `1`, is not needed.

Comment: Not necessarily: having a seed value to start with in a reducer is always a good and safe idea… especially when you start using TypeScript and it actually uses the seed value to infer the correct return type.

Answer (score 1):

You should iterate over rows. So you need to change inner loop on this :

`for (j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++)`

```js
const array = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [3, 4],
  [7, 8, 9]
];

for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
let result = 1;
  for (j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
    result *= array[i][j]
  }
  console.log(result);
}
```

Comment: Thanks yeah I see what I should add to the inner loop.  For some reason still not seeing anything in the console with what you provided

Comment: @ramango Whats your expected result?

Comment: expecting three numbers printed, each the result of multiplying the contents of each array

Comment: @ramango this is what you get if you click on **Run code snippet button**

Comment: True--i'll check what's goin on Thx!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, it is easier using map and reduce functions. `arr.map(array => array.reduce(arrayMult, 1))` is the multiplication of each inner array, like `[ 6, 12, 504 ]`, and the last reduce is to multiply these values.

```
var arr = [[1, 2, 3],[3, 4],[7, 8, 9]];
const arrayMult = (prev, curr) => prev * curr;
const total = arr.map(array => array.reduce(arrayMult, 1)).reduce(arrayMult, 1);
```

Comment: The reduce method's 2nd parameter, here the initial value of `1`, is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with good old iterating; your existing approach only had one bug, on the inner loop you were still checking the length of the top-level array instead of the inner array; `j` should range from 0 to `arr[i].length`, not `arr.length`.

An alternative approach uses map and reduce; comments below explain how it works:

```js
var arr = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [3, 4],
  [7, 8, 9]
]

console.log(
  arr.map(a => {  // <-- calls a function on each element of arr, 
                  // leaving the results in an array
    return a.reduce( // <-- reducer is like map, calling a function 
                     // on each element of a,  but collects its results
                     // in a "collector" variable passed to each step
      (val, sum) => {return val * sum}, // <-- multiply this value with 
                                        // the ones so far
      1 // <-- initial value for the collector
    )
  })
)
```

Comment: The reduce method's 2nd parameter, here the initial value of `1`, is not needed.

Comment: Strictly speaking you can get away with leaving it out in this case -- but I think it's safer and easier to reason about to explicitly init the collector.

Answer (score 0):

One approach was to iterate the array of arrays via [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) which for each array puts the product of all of its items where the latter gets achieved via a multiplying [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) task.

```js
console.log([

  [1, 2, 3],
  [3, 4],
  [7, 8, 9],

].map(arr =>
  arr.reduce((x, y) => x * y)
));
```